# Savefig error with hist2d and unequal bins

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to make a 2d histogram, but kept coming up with an error with savefig. The error only seems to arise when using bins of unequal size in hist2d.
Has anyone any insight?

Here is a simple code that replicates the fault:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# This works...
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
x = np.random.randn(100000)
y = np.random.randn(100000)+5
h=ax1.hist2d(x,y,bins=([0,1,2,3],(2,3,4,5,6)))
fig1.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()

# This fails...(note unequal bin sizes)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
x = np.random.randn(100000)
y = np.random.randn(100000)+5
h=ax1.hist2d(x,y,bins=([0,1,2,3],(2,3,5,6)))
fig1.savefig('test2.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

The error message I get is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unequal_bins.py", line 15, in <module>
    fig1.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
  File "/Users/earpwl/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1573, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/earpwl/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2210, in print_figure
    bbox = a.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/Users/earpwl/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 757, in get_window_extent
    x0, x1, y0, y1 = self._extent
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The code runs fine for me using matplotlib 2.1.1

Comment: I can reproduce this using matplotlib 2.1 on python 2.7. The problem seems to be related to the use of `bbox_inches='tight'`. If you remove this, it runs fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8426) with matplotlib <= 2.1.0.

A solution is either to leave out the `bbox_inches='tight'` argument to `savefig` or, as stated in that issue, to add

```
h[-1].set_extent(h[-1].get_extent())
```

Complete solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x = np.random.randn(100000)
y = np.random.randn(100000)+5
h=ax1.hist2d(x,y,bins=[[0,1,2,3],[2,3,5,6]])

h[-1].set_extent(h[-1].get_extent())

fig1.savefig('test2.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Updating matplotlib to the newest version is of course also an option. ;-)